# BFS to find all shortest paths between source S and multiple destination

Tags: python-3.x, graph, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, shortest-path

I have an algorithm that can find a path between a source S and a destination D without passing by the vertice in N. Now I want to modify the algorithm to find all shortest paths between a source S and a multiple destination.

```
# Python implementation to find the
# shortest path in the graph using
# dictionaries

# Function to find the shortest
# path between two nodes of a graph
def BFS_SP(graph, start, goal,N):
    explored = []
    
    # Queue for traversing the
    # graph in the BFS
    queue = [[start]]
    
    # If the desired node is
    # reached
    if start == goal:
        print("Same Node")
        return []
    
    # Loop to traverse the graph
    # with the help of the queue
    while queue:
        path = queue.pop(0)
        node = path[-1]
        
        # Condition to check if the
        # current node is not visited
        if node not in explored and node not in N:
            neighbours = graph.edges[node]
            
            # Loop to iterate over the
            # neighbours of the node
            for neighbour in neighbours:
                new_path = list(path)
                new_path.append(neighbour)
                queue.append(new_path)
                
                # Condition to check if the
                # neighbour node is the goal
                if neighbour == goal:
                    print("Shortest path = ", new_path)
                    return new_path
            explored.append(node)

    # Condition when the nodes
    # are not connected
    print("So sorry, but a connecting"\
                "path doesn't exist :(")
    return []


#BFS_SP(graph, 'A', 'D')
```

Comment: Create a loop and run your code for each destination?

Comment: That increases the time complexity, mainly because I need to find the diameter of a rooted graph and I have a loop at each time I need to compute de diameter so that will take a lot of time to finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to change your condition "if neighbour == goal:". When you reach that line you already have the shortest path for "neighbour" which is "new_path" and don't forget to add a condition at the beginning to print the shortest path when the target is the source.

Comment: Please that modification increases the complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: No, your complexity is the same, O(V^2 + E). This is my version in C++ https://ideone.com/OvuX50. Note that you can do better when you have u unique target in O(V + E) by keeping a predecessor graph in your exploration of nodes.